# Title of listing is missing

Tags: listings

I am using the `listings` package to mark-up C and Assembler code. Unfortunately the title of the listing is missing (the same with the `caption=...` command).

In the document section I using my `clisting` statement for C code and `asmlisting` for Assembler (both the same problem).

Here a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\lstnewenvironment{asmlisting}{
    \lstset{
        language={[x86masm]Assembler},
        basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
        breaklines=true,
        prebreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
        frame=lines,
        tabsize=2,
        showtabs=false,
        showspaces=false,
        showstringspaces=false,
        keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
        stringstyle=\color{green!50!black},
        commentstyle=\color{green}\itshape,
        numbers=none,
        captionpos=t,
        escapeinside={\%*}{*)},
        extendedchars=true,
    }
}{}

\newcommand{\clistingset}{
        \lstset{
        language=C,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
        breaklines=true,
        prebreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
        frame=lines,
        tabsize=2,
        showtabs=false,
        showspaces=false,
        showstringspaces=false,
        keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
        stringstyle=\color{green!50!black},
        commentstyle=\color{green}\itshape,
        numbers=none,
        captionpos=t,
        escapeinside={\%*}{*)},}
}



\begin{document}

\section*{Kap. 1}

\subsection*{Aufgabe 1}

\begin{asmlisting}[title=hallo] % this title is not displayed in the comp. doc.
 .INCLUDE "usb1287def.inc"
 .ORG    0

 start:
    ldi r16, 4
    clr r17

 loop:
    add r17, r16
    cpi r17, 32
    brne loop

 end:
    rjmp end
\end{asmlisting}

\cleardoublepage
\section*{Kap. 14}

\clistingset
% remarked to prevent compilation errors. This title is displayed in the comp. doc.
%\lstinputlisting[title=Aufg1.c]{Ueb14/Aufg1.c}

\end{document}
```

Does anyone have an idea what I'am doing wrong?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Ok, just updated my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following MWE you can see how to get the title.

You can define an own style (`clist`) or you have to rewrite your new environment (see manual page 42).  I personaly would use an own style, because I have not to remember, that I have to include the title with the new environment without `title=`.

MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{HelloWorld.c}
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    puts("Hallo Welt!");
    return 0;
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstnewenvironment{clisting}[1][]%
{\lstset{
  language=C,
  title=#1,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
  breaklines=true,
  prebreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
  frame=lines,
  tabsize=2,
  showtabs=false,
  showspaces=true,
  showstringspaces=false,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
  stringstyle=\color{green!50!black},
  commentstyle=\color{green}\itshape,
  numbers=none,
  captionpos=t,
  escapeinside={\%*}{*)},
 }
}{}

\lstdefinestyle{clist}{%  
  language=C,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
  breaklines=true,
  prebreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
  frame=lines,
  tabsize=2,
  showtabs=false,
  showspaces=true,
  showstringspaces=false,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
  stringstyle=\color{green!50!black},
  commentstyle=\color{green}\itshape,
  numbers=none,
  captionpos=t,
}


\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[title=HelloWorld.c]{HelloWorld.c}

\lstinputlisting[%
  title=HelloWorld.c
 ,style=clist
]{HelloWorld.c}

\section*{Kap. 1}
\subsection*{Aufgabe 1}

\begin{clisting}[hallo]
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    puts("Hallo Welt!");
    return 0;
}
\end{clisting}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Now it works! I decided to create a new style, as you recommended. It looks for me more proper while using different languages.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can't put anything after `\begin{asmlisting}[title=hallo]`, i.e. comments are not allowed.

Moreover, defining the new environment `asmlisting` as you did doesn't work.

You have to define it in this way:

```
\lstnewenvironment{asmlisting}[1][]{%
    \lstset{
        language={[x86masm]Assembler},
        basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
        breaklines=true,
        prebreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
        frame=lines,
        tabsize=2,
        showtabs=false,
        showspaces=false,
        showstringspaces=false,
        keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
        stringstyle=\color{green!50!black},
        commentstyle=\color{green}\itshape,
        numbers=none,
        captionpos=t,
        escapeinside={\%*}{*)},
        extendedchars=true,
        #1
    }
}{}
```

Thus your modified MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\lstnewenvironment{asmlisting}[1][]{%
    \lstset{
        language={[x86masm]Assembler},
        basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
        breaklines=true,
        prebreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
        frame=lines,
        tabsize=2,
        showtabs=false,
        showspaces=false,
        showstringspaces=false,
        keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
        stringstyle=\color{green!50!black},
        commentstyle=\color{green}\itshape,
        numbers=none,
        captionpos=t,
        escapeinside={\%*}{*)},
        extendedchars=true,
        #1
    }
}{}

\newcommand{\clistingset}{
        \lstset{
        language=C,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
        breaklines=true,
        prebreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
        frame=lines,
        tabsize=2,
        showtabs=false,
        showspaces=false,
        showstringspaces=false,
        keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
        stringstyle=\color{green!50!black},
        commentstyle=\color{green}\itshape,
        numbers=none,
        captionpos=t,
        escapeinside={\%*}{*)},}
}



\begin{document}

\section*{Kap. 1}

\subsection*{Aufgabe 1}

\begin{asmlisting}[title=hallo]
 .INCLUDE "usb1287def.inc"
 .ORG    0

 start:
    ldi r16, 4
    clr r17

 loop:
    add r17, r16
    cpi r17, 32
    brne loop

 end:
    rjmp end
\end{asmlisting}

\cleardoublepage
\section*{Kap. 14}

\clistingset
% remarked to prevent compilation errors. This title is displayed in the comp. doc.
%\lstinputlisting[title=Aufg1.c]{Ueb14/Aufg1.c}

\end{document}
```

will produce the desired output

[image]