# How can insert a full-width listing in a two-column document?

Tags: listings, two-column, code

I'm new to LaTeX; I'm using IEEE format. How can I effectively add Java code snippets in one full-width column?

Comment: You mean `verbatim`? Or the `listings` package?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Related? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3251/double-column-listing-package

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Ah okay, good to know that. It's using `listings`

Comment: @Papiro: That was a good suggestion.

Comment: @Papiro: How can I add a title for this code snippet ?

Comment: @JilTom http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129251/title-of-listing-is-missing